# How to execute subscribe into another subscribe in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I guess my problem has a pretty simple solution but I did not find one.
I want to write the value of the second subscribe

```
 export class ArticleDetailComponent implements OnInit  {

  private  articleID: any;
  public   detailArticle: any ;


  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute , private _articlesService: ArticlesService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit () {
     this.route.params.subscribe( (params) => {
      this.articleID = params['id'];
       this._articlesService.getArticle(this.articleID).subscribe( article => this.detailArticle = article );
     }
    );
  }
}
```

I want to write the value of the second subscribe into "`detailArticle`"
But because I already call one Subscribe , i think there is a difference in the requests and the time they arrive.
And in the value it records a "undefined" 
How can I sync the two Subscribes()  when one of them is into another ?
The idea is to set the resulting value of `detailArticle` So I can use it in the template .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `switchMap` operator of rxjs (see its docs [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap)):

```
this.route.params
          .do(params => this.articleID = params['id'])
          .switchMap(
            params => this._articlesService.getArticle(this.articleID)
          )
          .subscribe( article => this.detailArticle = article );
```

In plain words it takes your params observable and starts a new observable that gets your article and the result is merged back into the original observable and, therefore, available in your subscription.